# Why does my build complain that an environment variable is missing when I can plainly see that it exists?

Tags: php, travis-ci

I have a travis-ci [build](https://travis-ci.org/gettyimages/gettyimages-api_php/builds/61545922) setup to build a PHP project. When the build runs, it fails during the test run stating:

```
Environment var: GettyImagesApi_ApiKey was not found in the environment (Exception)
```

This happened previously and I deleted the environment variable, re-created it, then re-ran the build and it stopped throwing an exception. Now it has started throwing the exception again and deleting and re-creating the environment variable is not helping.

By the way, this environment variable is set in the GUI, not in the `.travis.yml` file.

After doing a few more builds, I've noticed that [sometimes](https://travis-ci.org/gettyimages/gettyimages-api_php/builds/61793823) I see this in the build log:

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings  
$ export GettyImagesApi_ApiSecret=[secure]  
$ export GettyImagesApi_UserName=[secure]  
$ export GettyImagesApi_UserPassword=[secure]  
$ export GettyImagesApi_ApiKey=[secure]
```

and of course, the environment variables are available. Sometimes I don't see those lines and then the environment variables don't exist.

What would cause the build to skip exporting the environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Reading is always good:

From the [documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Using-Settings)

> "...we do not expose these values to untrusted builds, triggered by pull requests from another repository."

The builds that were failing were pull requests. Builds from the main repo get the proper environment variables.